# I want to open incognito mode in web page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, incognito-mode

I am working with a web-page or a user-script (It's not about chrome extension) and as per my requirement i wants to open incognito mode.

Here is my JavaScript Code:

```
$('#google_alert').on('click', function(e)
{
    swal({
        title: "Review Us",
        text: "You will be redirected to review us on google",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#09a275",
        confirmButtonText: "Positive",
        cancelButtonText: "Negative",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: true
    }, function(isConfirm)
    {
        if(isConfirm)
        {
            chrome.windows.create({"url": "http://www.google.com", "incognito": true});

        swal("Thank you", "Thank you reviewing us.", "success");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#review-modal").modal('show');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

> Response: ReferenceError: chrome is not defined

Here is procedure of what i am doing,

1. click on google review option on web page,
2. it will redirect user to google review page,
3. google ask to login,
4. user enter credential and provide review,
5. back to web page.

Here you can see that no need to save user's ID and passwords into browser.

Comment: The `windows` part of the `chrome` object is only available when running as an extension. What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: _Here is my PHP script:_ That does not look like PHP

Comment: i update question. i am not developing chrome extension looking for webpage

Comment: already tried  : How to open new incognito window with Javascript? (Google Chrome)   but not working.@RiggsFolly